# Publishing Taxonomy, Shows Success but No Entry in the Broker Database table

Tags: 2011, publishing, taxonomy

I am publishing pages in Tridion and they are working well but when I published one category it shows success message, mapping in config file says its going into broker database, I am looking into "ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS" table but i don't have my category published there, how can i verify and there are no errors in log.?

I am getting continues warning mesages in log, Are these messages ignorable?

**WARN  FSTaxonomyDAO - TaxonomyDAO is set to File System, which is not supported. Check your bindings settings and/or license file.**

Comment: Check TAX_FACETS table

Comment: And that warning should not be ignored, something is misconfigured

Comment: Could your license have expired? The broker defaults to FS if you don't have a valid license

Comment: license is valid untill july 2014

Comment: are there no other warnings in the log file (can you log in debug mode) ? Could you also check if your cd_storage config xml file is valid. I remember seeing something similar when i had an error in my storage config, result was all mappings were set to the filesystem by default.

Comment: can you share your cd_storage_config file section where you can find that mapping for taxonomy is for broker DB

Also, can you make sure you are not referring to the wrong instance of DB

Answer (score 4):

Do you have **defaultStorageId** set to filesystem?

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true">
```

If so, add

```
<Item typeMapping="Taxonomy" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
```

Also, check that your broker database connections are correct, and that other items types are appearing in the broker.

Also, as Chris says above.. check licence files, as Tridion won't publish to the broker if the license has expired / invalid for machine.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong table, as mentioned by Nuno Linhares "TAX_FACETS" is the right table for storing taxonomies.